# Algebraic fundamental group of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I have a very explicit question. Consider a projective variety (a Fano 3-fold) in $\mathbb P^{10}$ defined by 3 quadrics and 32 cubic equations. I want to show that the algebraic fundamental group of the variety is {1}. Is there a way to show it?

Comment: Is your "Fano 3fold" smooth over the complex numbers?  If so, the fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: The Fano 3-fold is not smooth. It has 24 singularities. But if I take a quadric section of this Fano 3-fold then it is a smooth surface of general type.  Also Can you please provide me the reference for your above statement.

Comment: One reference is Section 3.4 of the following article of Olivier Debarre: http://archive.numdam.org/article/SB_2001-2002__44__243_0.pdf

Comment: It is true for normal (and more generally geometrically unibranch) complex varieties that the etale fundamental group is the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group. The topological fundamental group may be computable, so I hope this helps.

Comment: @JoeBerner.  Typically in these cases, we know that the algebraic fundamental group is trivial, but that (alone) does not prove that the topological fundamental group is trivial (if it is an infinite simple group, for instance).

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks Jason. Does it matter if the singularity is terminal or not, that is, if we have a Fano 3-fold with one terminal singularity then what about its algebraic fundamental group.

Comment: If the singularities are at worst Kawamata log terminal, then Qi Zhang (and later Hacon-McKernan in their solution to the Shokurov conjecture) proved that every desingularization is rationally connected, and hence simply connected (Section 3.4 of the article above).  Since terminal singularities are normal, it follows that your original scheme is also simply connected (I am assuming that you are working over a characteristic $0$ field).

Answer (score 5):

I am just collecting my comments above as an answer.  Over $\mathbb{C}$ (or any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$), every log $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano variety is simply connected.  A **log $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano variety** is a pair $(X,D)$ of a normal projective variety $X$ and an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $(X,D)$ has at worst Kawamata log terminal singularities and $-(K_X+D)$ is nef and big.  For such a pair $(X,D)$, for every desingularization $\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X$, $\widetilde{X}$ is rationally connected: this is a theorem of Qi Zhang.

MR2208131 (2006m:14021) 
Zhang, Qi(1-MO) 
Rational connectedness of log Q-Fano varieties. (English summary) 
 
J. Reine Angew. Math. 590 (2006), 131–142. 
14E30 (14J45) 
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408301

This was reproved by Hacon and M<sup>c</sup>Kernan 
as part of their proof of the Shokurov conjecture.

For a smooth projective variety that is rationally connected in characteristic $0$, or more generally if it is separably rationally connected in any characteristic, the variety is algebraically simply connected.  This was first proved over $\mathbb{C}$ by Campana (who also proves that the topological fundamental group of the underlying complex manifold is finite, so that the complex manifold is simply connected).  In positive characteristic this was proved by Kollár.  One nice reference is Section 3.4 of the following.

MR2074059 (2005g:14096) 
Debarre, Olivier(F-STRAS-I) 
Variétés rationnellement connexes (d'après T. Graber, J. Harris, J. Starr et A. J. de Jong). 
Séminaire Bourbaki. Vol. 2001/2002. 
Astérisque No. 290 (2003), Exp. No. 905, ix, 243–266. 
 
14M20 (14D06) 
https://eudml.org/doc/110309

Since normal varieties are unibranch, the fundamental group of $X$ is the image of the fundamental group of $\widetilde{X}$ (in general the surjective group homomorphism can have nontrivial kernel -- e.g., for cones over plane curves of degree $d\geq 3$).  Since $\widetilde{X}$ is simply connected, also $X$ is simply connected.

Of course it is also important to understand the fundamental group of the smooth locus of $X$.  I believe the best results for the smooth locus of $X$ are due to Chenyang Xu, who proves that the algebraic fundamental group of the smooth locus is finite.

Comment: Plain HTML works well:  M<sup>c</sup>Kernan.